# How can I find the x position of objects in a linked list in Java?

Tags: java

I am making a simple rhythm game in java which includes an object called beat which will move on a rail towards a stationary player. I need to compare the x position of the beat objects to the player but due to the way the beats are instantiated, I cannot directly call methods on them as far as I can tell.

I think the best solution would be some kind of loop of the linked list containing all the game objects but I'm not sure how to go about it.

GameObject:

```
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class GameObject {

    protected int x, y;
    protected ID id;
    protected int velX, velY;

    public GameObject(int x, int y, ID id){
        this.x = x;
        this. y = y;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public abstract void tick();
    public abstract void render(Graphics g);


    // getters and setters for class variables below here (already in in code just removed for uncecessary space.)

}
```

Beat:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Beat extends GameObject{
    public Beat(int x, int y, ID id) {
        super(x, y, id);

        velX= -3;
    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        x+= velX;
       // System.out.println(this.getX());
    }


    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x,y,50,50);
    }
}
```

Instantiation:

```
    handler.addObject(new Beat(800,300,ID.Beat));
    handler.addObject(new Beat(1000,300,ID.Beat));
    handler.addObject(new Player(100,300,ID.Player));
```

Handler:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

//Handler class is responsible for updating and rendering all game objects

    public class Handler {
    
        LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();
    
        public void tick(){
            //loops through every object
            for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
                // sets temp object to linked list function which gets the ID of the current object
                GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
    
                tempObject.tick();
            }
        }
    
        public void render(Graphics g){
            //renders every object
            for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
                GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
    
                //renders the temp object
                tempObject.render(g);
            }
        }
    
        public void addObject(GameObject object){
            //linked list built in method to add an object
            this.object.add(object);
        }
    
        public void removeObject(GameObject object){
            //linked list built in method
            this.object.remove(object);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opted for a different solution entirely, utilising a linked list as a queue, which allows the first object to easily be called and the x value checked.

For details please refer here: [How can I use a Linked list with my Handler class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70133505/how-can-i-use-a-linked-list-with-my-handler-class-in-java)