# How can I use a Linked list with my Handler class in Java?

Tags: java

I am making a simple game which has an array of objects called beats which move along the screen towards a stationary player like a basic rhythm game, and I have decided that using a linked list is the best way to track the nearest beat to the player

Currently I am trying to add to the linked list, and have this as a starting point:

```
     public static LinkedList<Beat> beatLinkedList = new LinkedList<Beat>();
```

The linked list is public and static as it needs to be accessed in a different class.

```
        int startingPoint = 800;
        //For loop 51 times
        for(int i=0;i<=50;i++){
            //modifier to start position to create differing gaps between beats
            int startModifier = random.nextInt(50);


            beatLinkedList.add(new Beat(startingPoint,300,ID.Beat));
            System.out.println(beatLinkedList.get(0));

            //redefines the starting point for each beat
            startingPoint = startingPoint+50+startModifier;

        }
    }
```

When I want to render the objects however I need to use the handler class, to add the objects to a linked list of gameobjects which has the render method called on them which I would like to keep the same ideally meaning I need to use the handler classes `addObject` method:

```
 public void addObject(GameObject object){
        //linked list built in method to add an object
        this.object.add(object);
    }
```

For using an array this solution worked

But something similar for the linked list does not

```
 handler.addObject(beatLinkedList.add(new Beat(startingPoint,300,ID.Beat)));
```

I should also add that when I get the element at position 0 it outputs all 51 objects which is also a problem.

With trying to use the handler like this I am given an exception saying `"addoObject in Handler cannot be applied to boolean"`on line 50:

```
 handler.addObject(beatLinkedList.add(new Beat(startingPoint,300,ID.Beat)));
```

I'm not sure about this but it seems that I need to give a pointer to a location when using the add method and so I tried this:

```
beatLinkedList.addLast(new Beat(startingPoint,300,ID.Beat));
```

And this method still has the problem of adding all 51 objects to the same point in the list, which I imagine is something to do with being in a for loop still.

```
    handler.addObject(beatLinkedList.addLast(new Beat(startingPoint,300,ID.Beat)));
```

Trying to utilise this with my handler class results in a different error from before saying that the 'void' type is not allowed as a parameter. I'm really not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The result I'm getting is that nothing renders because I am not passing the linked list objects to the handler class as I mentioned, and showed an example of it with an array which was working. The desired behaviour is that the beats are added to the gameObject linked list, as well as being added to the new linked list for beats exclusively

Comment: Also, mentioned the previous question as it is somewhat of a continuation, but because the problem is completely different now I didn't link it, either way this was the question from before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70126163/how-can-i-prevent-these-ranges-from-overlapping-in-java?noredirect=1#comment123965903_70126163

Comment: Yes that's the entire line 50, I think I need to write the line in some different way though, handler.addObject is esentially just adding to another linked list, so I think the syntax should be different here.

Comment: I'm wondering why linkedlist.add would return a boolean as its meant to take an object as an argument, no?

Comment: Not sure if I've got this right but does that mean I have to provide a insertion point? I thought add method would just add at the end of the linked list `Parameters:
index - index at which the specified element is to be inserted
element - element to be inserted`

Comment: `beatLinkedList.addLast(new Beat(startingPoint,300,ID.Beat));  handler.addObject(beatLinkedList.getLast());`

Comment: Thank you, doing this seperately seems to work, just working on reading the first element in the list and then deleting it once the player inputs. I did also have to change`handler.addObject(beatLinkedList.getLast());` to  `handler.addObject((GameObject) beatLinkedList.getLast());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    beatLinkedList.addLast(new Beat(startingPoint,300,ID.Beat));  
handler.addObject(beatLinkedList.getLast());
```

Solved thanks to  Abra's comment, I decided to add the object to 2 seperate linked lists, one of just the beats, and one containing all the game objects, which allows them to be rendered properly, while also allowing beats to be identified and removed when necessary.